# How do you use named router-views with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do you use named router-views with Typescript? I set up my router index.ts per documentation:

```
<component>
  <v-content style="padding: 0 0 0 180px">
     <router-view name="settings"/>
  </v-content>
</component>

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/Members',
    name: 'Members',
    component: { settings: Members}
  },
]
```

But when I try to run, I get this error:

```
Argument of type '{ mode: "history"; base: string | undefined; routes: ({ path: string; name: string; component: { settings: typeof Members; }; 
} | { path: string; name: string; component: typeof Home; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouterOptions'.
  Types of property 'routes' are incompatible.
    Type '({ path: string; name: string; component: { settings: typeof MyAccount; }; } | { path: string; name: string; component: typeof Home; })[]' i
s not assignable to type 'RouteConfig[]'.
      Type '{ path: string; name: string; component: { settings: typeof MyAccount; }; } | { path: string; name: string; component: typeof Home; }' is 
not assignable to type 'RouteConfig'.
        Type '{ path: string; name: string; component: { settings: typeof Members; }; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteConfig'.
          Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
            Type '{ settings: typeof Members; }' is not assignable to type 'VueConstructor<Vue> | ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<...>, Record<...>> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...> | undefined'.
              Type '{ settings: typeof Members; }' is not assignable to type 'AsyncComponentFactory<DefaultData<never>, DefaultMethods<never>, DefaultComputed, Record<string, any>>'.
                Type '{ settings: typeof MyAccount; }' provides no match for the signature '(): { component: AsyncComponentPromise<DefaultData<never>, DefaultMethods<never>, DefaultComputed, Record<string, any>>; loading?: VueConstructor<...> | ... 3 more ... | undefined; error?: VueConstructor<...> | ... 3 more ... | undefined; delay?: number | undefined; timeout?: number | undefined; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out... I had to take a look at the router.d.ts file to see what type they were looking for. If you want to use named router-views you have to add an s to component in your code because the file checks for this format:

```
components?: Dictionary<Component>

type Dictionary<T> = {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```